# In a JSF 2.0 app, how can i get a huge array of data into my javascript code from the ManagedBean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2.0 app where I need to get from the server side ManagedBean a huge amount of data to load into a multidimensional array of about 7000 javascript objects for graphic display. Ultimately these objects will be edited by the app and returned to the server for storage back in the db they came from, so transport in both directions would be needed.

The usual ways to get and set data via hidden h:inputText items wont handle this sort of volume. I also tried to do an ajax call from my client side code but I cant figure out what url to use to get to my session's ManagedBean. It seems like this should be possible somehow ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use servlets for retrieving and processing data with jquery ajax

Servlet  class :

```
    @WebServlet("/jsonservlet/*")
    public class JSONServlet extends HttpServlet {




        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException{

           //use any json library ( I recommended gson library)

            response.setContentType("application/json");            

           response.getWriter().write(jsonData)
        }
    }
```

now you can make ajax call to this servlet using jquery to retrieve the json returned data

```
$.ajax({
        url: "jsonservlet",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',

        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',

        success: function (data) {
            //here you can populate your javascript array 
        },
        error:function(data,status,er) {
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know how to send the ajax request from the client side, but I did not get a reply. I was unable to get the correct url to reach the generated server side ManagedBean for the JSF app, or if I did get there, I didn't know what sort of function to write to return the right data in the right format. The ManagedBean is transformed by its annotations into some other object. How do I 1) get the correct url to send to and 2) catch and reply from the managed bean ?

Comment: to clarify a bit more: The @ManagedBean Pojo for the JSF application has to be turned into an extension of the HttpServlet class, or the JSF xhtml file full of <h:inputText> and other neat stuff wouldn't work in the first place. It is *that* instance that I want to answer my ajax request. But the details are a bit hidden by the magic of annotation ... when I try the app's URL, even specified in full (http://localhost:8080/Wacht/mapedit.jsf) I don't seem to reach the bean ...